# Android error “Failed to connect to the network. Please check you network connection status”

Tags: networking, connection-issues

I'm using lenovo p2 phone. I'm getting following popup error every few seconds. It is very annoying.My mobile data connection is on. But it is showing " Failed to connect to the network. Please check you network connection status" . I have attached the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]